# How to write scoped storage for android 11 in java?

Tags: java, android, storage, android-11, scoped-storage

Here is my app code below. I want to store images and files such as pdf to my folder path to the above 10+ version and below version. I just want to know. Is the correct way? please let me know what I have missed. It's working perfectly but I just confused with manifest permission as per google play policy for app successful update

my question is the correct way for scoped storage and permissions?

my manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.flendzz.licstickynote.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity.java

```
    private void SaveImageaBOVE10(Bitmap bitmap) {
            OutputStream fos;
            try {
    
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "image_" + ".jpg");
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "Note App");
    
                    Uri imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                    fos = (FileOutputStream) contentResolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    Objects.requireNonNull(fos);
    
                    Toast.makeText(this, "image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                } else {
    
                
    
                        SaveImage(bitmap);
              
    
                }
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }
    

//below 10 version

    private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/NoteApp");
            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                myDir.mkdirs();
            }
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            Toast.makeText(this, "image saved in storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: i want to store images

Comment: is this ok with the manifest permission ?

Comment: to my internal storage. what is the correct way?

Comment: updated my question. please check

Comment: No idea ? @blackapps

Comment: `such as pdf to my folder path ` More than two hours ago i asked you to specify your folder path on the first line of your post. You still did not do that. I do not want to search in your code which path you mean so thell it THERE on the first line. I'm waiting and waiting...